# Little help for one CSS trick: chained Pseudo element/classes

Tags: css

Want to create class "My-Tag" for any a, p, label, etc... to be surrounded with bracket like html tag.
In this case <> bracket need to be Blue, / slash gray, normal text gray, and hover white. I'm stack on adding content after "content". Pseudo elements can't be chained (two in a row). :)
This almost working ok, but not the last one ">"

```css
.My-tag {color: gray;}
.My-tag:hover {color: white}
.My-tag::before {
    color: royalblue;
    content: "<";
}
.My-tag:after {
    color: gray;
    content: "/";
}
.My-tag::after::after {
    color: royalblue;
    content: ">";
}
```

```html
<label class="My-tag">SomeText<label/>
```

Comment: Chained afters don't work, could you use JS to insert an empty node on every label? That would give you some nested items to style.

Comment: I know how to with JS, but really, isn't possible through CSS?

Comment: I've come up with a possible CSS-only solution for you as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single :after where you include both characters then apply a text-gradient from left to right to achieve the look you want.

```
.My-tag:after {
  content: "/>";
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, gray 50%, royalblue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I can't guarantee cross-browser support, that's only tested in Chrome. It's also likely to cause issues if you ever have a line break between the 2 characters for some reason.

This is the only CSS-only way I can think to do it, I would recommend taking the JS approach though.

Comment: This is closest solution, but not final. Different fonts, font size etc.. will do something... fun. :)
Char (i) and (E), not using the same space. 50% is not universal solution.
But definitely i the best way till now., thx.

Comment: Absolutely, you will come across many edge-cases following the CSS-only solution for this particular problem. This is why JS is still my recommendation, it's a more stable and predictable solution. However as your question was for CSS only I wanted to make sure I answered your question.